# spring thymleaf class not found exception : org.thymeleaf.doctype.DocTypeIdentifier

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have an application which use maven, spring framework and thymeleaf. I set up my template Engine and my template Resolver. But when i'm running it, I got an error saying it can not instanciate my template engine bean and the last ligne of the error is the following : 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.thymeleaf.doctype.DocTypeIdentifier 
I'm guessing it is missing some dependencies. 
My template Engine and resolver are the following :

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ITemplateResolver thymeleafTemplateResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("mail-templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine thymeleafTemplateEngine(ITemplateResolver templateResolver) {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(emailMessageSource());
    return templateEngine;
}
```

My dependencies are :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Am I missing some dependencies ? or is my version wrong ?

Comment: YOu are mixing versions, don't. ALso use `thymeleaf-spring5` (as that is the version Spring Boot 2.4 is using) and remove the `version` tag for your dependencies (those are managed by Spring Boot already).

Comment: I still got that missing class error ... But thanks !

Comment: Then you must be using something that is incompatible but that you left out of the question.